# Jqplot barchart on hover color change and show custom tooltip

Tags: css, jqplot, bar-chart

I am trying to show a graph using jqplot and I want to change the color when the user hovers on any chart element. Currently, they have a default color set, whenever user hovers on a graph.

I have two difficulties in this...

I am not able to understand how should I change the on hover color 
and how can I have a custom tooltip.

I need something like this,[image]

As of now, I get the graph but somehow I am not able to show the tooltip on the correct position, neither am i able to change the color from blue to green. my tooltip is not properly setup.

I tried binding my graph with jqplotDataHighlight and use the mouse X and Y position to position my tool tip. But that doesnt work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As for the colour, I found this: "highlightColor"

As for the tooltip, I'm going to assume you've read their documentation, but just incase, heres a bit on the tolltip: http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-highlighter-js.html

Have you considered google charts? Either that or flotr2 is what I would suggest. Otherwise, good luck! I wish I could be more useful!

Comment: can some one help me how to implement this thing using q-tips?